# Show Post with its comments using ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am facing an issue in building below format in MVC using AngularJS
I am showing the posts from the facebook  using api with ng-repeat which consists of a Image.

Now the problem i am facing to show the comments for each of the posts using nested ng-repeat.

Dont have any idea how to proceed with it.

Comment: Could you supply any code? It would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat nested sample

http://plnkr.co/edit/NGWOZ4?p=info

I think you need something like that?

```
    <body ng-controller="programController">
  <div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="row in osk.programs">
    <div>{{row.day}}</div>
    <div>
      <h4>{{row.head}}</h4>
      <p>{{row.content}}</p>
      <aside class="warning" ng-repeat="row in row.extra">
        <strong>Ekstra Gezi:</strong> {{row.exhead}} &nbsp; <span>{{row.price}}</span>
        <p>{{row.excontent}}</p>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('programController', function($scope) {
    var json = {
        "programs":
            [
                {
                    "day":"1.GÜN",
                    "head":"İstanbul-Amsterdam",
                    "content":"Gezimizin ilk günü, kalkıştan iki saat önce Sabiha Gökçen Havalimanı Dış Hatlar Terminali Etstur Kontuarı önünde buluşarak başlıyor. Pegasus Hava Yolları tarifeli seferi ile Amsterdam’a uçuş. Havalimanında bizleri bekleyen otobüsümüz ile Amsterdam şehir turu. Bu gezide Tarihi Tren İstasyonu, Dam Meydanı, Ajax Arena Stadı, Tarihi Çiçek Pazarı ve yel değirmenleri görülecek yerlerden bazıları. Misafirlerimiz ekstra olarak düzenlenecek Amsterdam Kanallar Gezisi'ne katılabilirler. Şehir turu sonrası otele transfer. Öğleden sonra serbest zaman. Geceleme otelimizde.",
                    "extra":
                    [
                      {
                        "exhead":"Amsterdam kanallar gezisi", 
                        "price":"55 Euro",
                        "excontent":"Amsterdam’a farklı açıdan bakmak isteyenler için üzeri cam olan teknelerle Amsterdam’ın simgesi haline gelmiş kanalları arasında eğlenceli gezi sizi bekliyor."
                      },
                      {
                        "exhead":"Tekne Turu", 
                        "price":"15 Euro",
                        "excontent":"Amsterdam’a farklı açıdan bakmak isteyenler için üzeri"
                      }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    "day":"2.GÜN",
                    "head":"Amsterdam-Paris",
                    "content":"Gezimizin ilk günü, kalkıştan iki saat önce Sabiha Gökçen Havalimanı Dış Hatlar Terminali Etstur Kontuarı önünde buluşarak başlıyor. Pegasus Hava Yolları tarifeli seferi ile Amsterdam’a uçuş. Havalimanında bizleri bekleyen otobüsümüz ile Amsterdam şehir turu. Bu gezide Tarihi Tren İstasyonu, Dam Meydanı, Ajax Arena Stadı, Tarihi Çiçek Pazarı ve yel değirmenleri görülecek yerlerden bazıları. Misafirlerimiz ekstra olarak düzenlenecek Amsterdam Kanallar Gezisi'ne katılabilirler. Şehir turu sonrası otele transfer. Öğleden sonra serbest zaman. Geceleme otelimizde.",
                    "extra":
                    [
                      {
                        "exhead":"Amsterdam kanallar gezisi", 
                        "price":"55 Euro",
                        "excontent":"Amsterdam’a farklı açıdan bakmak isteyenler için üzeri cam olan teknelerle Amsterdam’ın simgesi haline gelmiş kanalları arasında eğlenceli gezi sizi bekliyor."
                      },
                      {
                        "exhead":"Tekne Turu", 
                        "price":"15 Euro",
                        "excontent":"Amsterdam’a farklı açıdan bakmak isteyenler için üzeri"
                      }
                    ]

                }
            ]
    };
    $scope.osk = json;
});
```

Comment: thanks @Braulio for the answer but  i need something else.                firstly i am  fetching the posts from api and the resulting json data is feeded to Parent ng -repeat. Secondly i want to fetch  comments  for each of the post shown above in their respective child ng-repeat on the base of postID.It should be done for each post simultaneously Hope you understand what i want ?

Comment: You can use the nested ng-repeat, binding will do all the magic for you (fetch entry, keep reference to that entry, once you have the $http request ready feed the entry.comments field and will automatically appear in your page), Angularjs binding is quite powerful